# Is Java 8 compatible with GWT 2.6 or 2.7?

Tags: java, gwt, java-8, compatibility

I have an application which is developed using GWT 2.6 and Java 7. Now I am updating it to Java 8 with GWT 2.6.

1. Is GWT 2.6 compatible with Java 8? Will it build/compile fine?
2. Is GWT 2.7 compatible with Java 8? Any suggestion?

Comment: yes i tried...getting exception

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're only interested in using a JDK 8 to compile your application, without using Java 8 language constructs, then GWT 2.6 and 2.7 will work.

Java 8 as a source language won't be supported before GWT 2.8 though, as already pointed by others.

Comment: Is it possible to use Java 8 language constructs on the server side in GWT 2.6 / 2.7, or is that not even possible? What's the advantage of using JDK 8 to compile, but not using java 8 language constructs?

Comment: Of course you can, as long as you have a Java 8 JVM to run it; it's just Java.

Comment: What I'd I cannot update to 2.6 because of dependencies?

Answer (score 3):

In 2.7, you can use the Java7 syntax on the client. You cannot use the Java8 syntax and runtime on the client.

On the server, you can use JDK8.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 support should come in GWT 2.8 according to this post: [Java 8 support in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693169/java-8-support-in-gwt).

So, basically you cannot use Java 8 in GWT 2.6. As I understand there are some improvements in 2.7, but it is not enough. There is a way that by dividing the project you can achieve that you can use Java 8 on the server side and java 7 with GWT on UI.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: you should take a look at this  [Java 8 support in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693169/java-8-support-in-gwt/15693528#15693528)

Comment: Please give attribution when you copy/paste someone else's answer (and it's even better if it doesn't look like you're the author but are just quoting someone else): https://stackoverflow.com/a/15693528/116472 It's even worth when you do it wrong and it looks like you're contradicting yourself (sic!) in just 2 sentences.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to be GWT 2.8 and 3.0.

> In the meantime, GWT 2.8 is due out within three months. Its main
>   feature is support for Java 8, including lambdas.

http://www.infoworld.com/article/2874861/application-development/google-web-toolkit-major-upgrades-no-backward-compatibility.html

Answer (score 0):

According to Release Notes for 2.8.0

> **Highlights**
>
> - Java 8 syntax supported.
> - JsInterop has graduated from experimental. See final JsInterop    specification.
> - GSS is no longer considered as experimental and old CssResource is    now deprecated.

http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_8_0_BETA1

**Update:**
Stable version of 2.8.0 is [released](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_8_0) on Oct 20, 2016