# Fatal error with Java 8

Tags: java-8, fatal-error, tomcat8, java

I am running a GWT / Spring / Hibernate based web-app on Tomcat 8 and we upgraded to Java 8 a while ago and things have been going well until this morning. All of a sudden the application crashed with some error that I cannot make heads or tails of and cannot find reported anywhere other than on the Minecraft site: http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/discussion/2374764-ftb-crash

I have reported the bug to the OpenJDK team but I know that they can take a while to respond and I am concerned that it happens again in the interim. The full crash report is too long but I have posted as much as possible below, if anyone has any insight as to why this issue occurs and how to workaround it, that would be great.

```
    #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  Internal Error (loopnode.hpp:609), pid=17, tid=139907756197632
    #  guarantee(n != NULL) failed: No Node.
    #
    # JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_66-b17) (build 1.8.0_66-internal-b17)
    # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.66-b17 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
    # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    #

    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread (0x00007f3ef00ee800):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=30, stack(0x00007f3ed00c0000,0x00007f3ed01c1000)]

    Stack: [0x00007f3ed00c0000,0x00007f3ed01c1000],  sp=0x00007f3ed01bbc60,  free space=1007k
    Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
    V  [libjvm.so+0xa8da7d]
    V  [libjvm.so+0x4e88e5]
    V  [libjvm.so+0x7cf30f]
    V  [libjvm.so+0x7cf204]
    V  [libjvm.so+0x7cf204]
    V  [libjvm.so+0x7cf218]
    V  [libjvm.so+0x7cf218]
    V  [libjvm.so+0x7cf218]
    V  [libjvm.so+0x7cf204]
    V  [libjvm.so+0x7d6ead]
    V  [libjvm.so+0x48a440]
    V  [libjvm.so+0x48c349]
    V  [libjvm.so+0x3d6981]
    V  [libjvm.so+0x498166]
    V  [libjvm.so+0x4996d7]
    V  [libjvm.so+0xa3237a]
    V  [libjvm.so+0x8da0f2]
    C  [libpthread.so.0+0x80a4]  start_thread+0xc4


    Current CompileTask:
    C2:120739200 48722 % !   4       za.co.bsg.ems.server.webservices.MWLWebServiceImpl$EmployeeImporter::run @ 5562 (7696 bytes)


    ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

    Java Threads: ( => current thread )
      0x00007f3ecc052800 JavaThread "ajp-nio-8009-exec-64" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2615, stack(0x00007f3e4be16000,0x00007f3e4bf17000)]
      0x00007f3ecc092800 JavaThread "ajp-nio-8009-exec-61" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2612, stack(0x00007f3e48baa000,0x00007f3e48cab000)]
      0x00007f3ed8086000 JavaThread "ajp-nio-8009-exec-60" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2591, stack(0x00007f3e488a7000,0x00007f3e489a8000)]
      0x00007f3ecc0a9000 JavaThread "ajp-nio-8009-exec-59" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2590, stack(0x00007f3e4c018000,0x00007f3e4c119000)]
      0x00007f3ed8081800 JavaThread "ajp-nio-8009-exec-58" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2589, stack(0x00007f3e4c21a000,0x00007f3e4c31b000)]
      0x00007f3ecc0f3800 JavaThread "ajp-nio-8009-exec-55" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2551, stack(0x00007f3e4c31b000,0x00007f3e4c41c000)]
      0x00007f3ecc0ce000 JavaThread "ajp-nio-8009-exec-54" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2548, stack(0x00007f3e47ea1000,0x00007f3e47fa2000)]
      0x00007f3ed80c8000 JavaThread "ajp-nio-8009-exec-51" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2545, stack(0x00007f3e49e10000,0x00007f3e49f11000)]
      0x00007f3ecc079800 JavaThread "ajp-nio-8009-exec-49" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2537, stack(0x00007f3e4bf17000,0x00007f3e4c018000)]
      0x00007f3ef0587800 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-6" [_thread_blocked, id=1325, stack(0x00007f3e480a3000,0x00007f3e481a4000)]
      0x00007f3ecc0ad000 JavaThread "ajp-nio-8009-exec-15" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=556, stack(0x00007f3e48aa9000,0x00007f3e48baa000)]
      0x000000000258d800 JavaThread "pool-6-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=206, stack(0x00007f3e49d0f000,0x00007f3e49e10000)]
      0x00007f3e5c046800 JavaThread "pool-4-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=191, stack(0x00007f3e4a311000,0x00007f3e4a412000)]
      0x0000000002821000 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=187, stack(0x00007f3ec8b93000,0x00007f3ec8c94000)]
      0x00007f3e6400f800 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=179, stack(0x00007f3ec8c94000,0x00007f3ec8d95000)]
      0x00007f3ef037c000 JavaThread "ajp-nio-8009-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=153, stack(0x00007f3e4c51d000,0x00007f3e4c61e000)]
      0x00007f3ef037a000 JavaThread "ajp-nio-8009-ClientPoller-1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=152, stack(0x00007f3e4c61e000,0x00007f3e4c71f000)]
      0x00007f3ef01c5000 JavaThread "ajp-nio-8009-ClientPoller-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=151, stack(0x00007f3ec848e000,0x00007f3ec858f000)]
      0x00007f3ef01c3800 JavaThread "http-nio-8080-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=150, stack(0x00007f3ec858f000,0x00007f3ec8690000)]
      0x00007f3ef01c1800 JavaThread "http-nio-8080-ClientPoller-1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=149, stack(0x00007f3ec8690000,0x00007f3ec8791000)]
      0x00007f3ef01c1000 JavaThread "http-nio-8080-ClientPoller-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=148, stack(0x00007f3ec8791000,0x00007f3ec8892000)]
      0x00007f3ef01bf000 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=147, stack(0x00007f3ec8892000,0x00007f3ec8993000)]
      0x00007f3e8578b000 JavaThread "javamelody app" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=146, stack(0x00007f3e4c71f000,0x00007f3e4c820000)]
      0x00007f3e879ca800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=145, stack(0x00007f3e76ade000,0x00007f3e76bdf000)]
      0x00007f3e7a3c3000 JavaThread "java-sdk-http-connection-reaper" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=142, stack(0x00007f3e4def9000,0x00007f3e4dffa000)]
      0x00007f3e86e60000 JavaThread "Hibernate Search sync consumer thread for index za.co.bsg.ems.server.model.entity.project.ProjectTag" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=141, stack(0x00007f3e4e7fa000,0x00007f3e4e8fb000)]
      0x00007f3e87360000 JavaThread "Hibernate Search sync consumer thread for index za.co.bsg.ems.server.model.entity.employee.Employee" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=140, stack(0x00007f3e4e8fb000,0x00007f3e4e9fc000)]
      0x00007f3e799d8800 JavaThread "Hibernate Search sync consumer thread for index za.co.bsg.ems.server.model.entity.tenantprofile.tenantgoal.TenantGoalTag" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=139, stack(0x00007f3e4e9fc000,0x00007f3e4eafd000)]
      0x00007f3e799d7000 JavaThread "Hibernate Search sync consumer thread for index za.co.bsg.ems.server.model.entity.employee.EmployeeTag" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=138, stack(0x00007f3e4eafd000,0x00007f3e4ebfe000)]
      0x00007f3e799d6000 JavaThread "Hibernate Search sync consumer thread for index za.co.bsg.ems.server.model.entity.recruitment.ApplicantTag" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=137, stack(0x00007f3e4ebfe000,0x00007f3e4ecff000)]
      0x00007f3e799d5800 JavaThread "Hibernate Search sync consumer thread for index za.co.bsg.ems.server.model.entity.social.Tag" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=136, stack(0x00007f3e4ecff000,0x00007f3e4ee00000)]
      0x00007f3e87814000 JavaThread "Hibernate Search sync consumer thread for index za.co.bsg.ems.server.model.entity.social.FeedPostTag" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=135, stack(0x00007f3e540c0000,0x00007f3e541c1000)]
      0x00007f3e799a3800 JavaThread "Hibernate Search sync consumer thread for index za.co.bsg.ems.server.model.entity.social.Group" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=134, stack(0x00007f3e766dc000,0x00007f3e767dd000)]
      0x00007f3e87bc7800 JavaThread "Hibernate Search sync consumer thread for index za.co.bsg.ems.server.model.entity.employee.Experience" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=133, stack(0x00007f3e554d7000,0x00007f3e555d8000)]
      0x00007f3e875e8000 JavaThread "__DEFAULT__" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=131, stack(0x00007f3e550d3000,0x00007f3e551d4000)]
      0x00007f3eac001800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=129, stack(0x00007f3e547cc000,0x00007f3e548cd000)]
      0x00007f3e85041800 JavaThread "customCacheManager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=128, stack(0x00007f3e54ed1000,0x00007f3e54fd2000)]
      0x00007f3ea4143000 JavaThread "cluster-events-processor-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=127, stack(0x00007f3e54fd2000,0x00007f3e550d3000)]
      0x00007f3e70010000 JavaThread "Job_Executor2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=125, stack(0x00007f3e551d4000,0x00007f3e552d5000)]
      0x00007f3e6c01f000 JavaThread "Job_Executor1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=124, stack(0x00007f3e552d5000,0x00007f3e553d6000)]
      0x00007f3e79afe800 JavaThread "Out of band notifier - Main" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=123, stack(0x00007f3e553d6000,0x00007f3e554d7000)]
      0x00007f3e843bd800 JavaThread "WorkerThread(lock_statistics_response_stage, 0)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=121, stack(0x00007f3e557d8000,0x00007f3e558d9000)]
      0x00007f3e85026000 JavaThread "WorkerThread(lock_response_stage, 0)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=120, stack(0x00007f3e558d9000,0x00007f3e559da000)]
      0x00007f3e85024000 JavaThread "WorkerThread(lock_statistics_enable_disable_stage, 0)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=119, stack(0x00007f3e559da000,0x00007f3e55adb000)]
      0x00007f3e85022000 JavaThread
...
      0x00007f3e84d6d000 JavaThread "Re-invalidation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=60, stack(0x00007f3e754d2000,0x00007f3e755d3000)]
      0x00007f3e84d6b000 JavaThread "RemoteServerMapManager Request Scheduler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=59, stack(0x00007f3e755d3000,0x00007f3e756d4000)]
      0x00007f3e84466800 JavaThread "RemoteObjectManager Request Scheduler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=58, stack(0x00007f3e756d4000,0x00007f3e757d5000)]
      0x00007f3e877dd000 JavaThread "Statistics Logger" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=57, stack(0x00007f3e757d5000,0x00007f3e758d6000)]
      0x00007f3e84c37800 JavaThread "RemoteTransactionManager Flusher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=56, stack(0x00007f3e758d6000,0x00007f3e759d7000)]
      0x00007f3e84761800 JavaThread "HealthChecker" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=55, stack(0x00007f3e75bd7000,0x00007f3e75cd8000)]
      0x00007f3e8456e000 JavaThread "L1_L2:TCComm Main Selector Thread_W (listen 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:49030)" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=54, stack(0x00007f3e75cd8000,0x00007f3e75dd9000)]
      0x00007f3e86a2d000 JavaThread "L1_L2:TCComm Main Selector Thread_R (listen 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:49030)" daemon [_thread_in_vm_trans, id=53, stack(0x00007f3e75dd9000,0x00007f3e75eda000)]
      0x00007f3e84108800 JavaThread "SampledCounterManager Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=52, stack(0x00007f3e75eda000,0x00007f3e75fdb000)]
      0x00007f3e84099000 JavaThread "startlevel job thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=51, stack(0x00007f3e75fdb000,0x00007f3e760dc000)]
      0x00007f3e86a50000 JavaThread "com.google.common.base.internal.Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=49, stack(0x00007f3e767dd000,0x00007f3e768de000)]
      0x00007f3e79d22000 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=47, stack(0x00007f3e772e2000,0x00007f3e773e3000)]
      0x00007f3e68102000 JavaThread "cluster-1-my24.co.za:27017" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=46, stack(0x00007f3e76fdf000,0x00007f3e770e0000)]
      0x00007f3e87adc000 JavaThread "MongoCleaner826696134" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=45, stack(0x00007f3e770e0000,0x00007f3e771e1000)]
      0x00007f3e87ab2000 JavaThread "cluster-1-mwldr.bsg.co.za:27023" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=44, stack(0x00007f3e771e1000,0x00007f3e772e2000)]
      0x00007f3e794d2800 JavaThread "cluster-1-demo.myworklife.com:27023" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=42, stack(0x00007f3e980fe000,0x00007f3e981ff000)]
      0x00007f3e845f6800 JavaThread "Abandoned connection cleanup thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=41, stack(0x00007f3ec8074000,0x00007f3ec8175000)]
      0x00007f3ef04d8000 JavaThread "NioBlockingSelector.BlockPoller-2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=38, stack(0x00007f3ec8d95000,0x00007f3ec8e96000)]
      0x00007f3ef04bd000 JavaThread "NioBlockingSelector.BlockPoller-1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=37, stack(0x00007f3ec8e96000,0x00007f3ec8f97000)]
      0x00007f3ef0430800 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=36, stack(0x00007f3ec91c5000,0x00007f3ec92c6000)]
      0x00007f3ef01a0000 JavaThread "AsyncFileHandlerWriter-640070680" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=35, stack(0x00007f3ec9afb000,0x00007f3ec9bfc000)]
      0x00007f3ef0100800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=33, stack(0x00007f3ec9cfd000,0x00007f3ec9dfe000)]
      0x00007f3ef00f5800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=32, stack(0x00007f3ec9dfe000,0x00007f3ec9eff000)]
      0x00007f3ef00f0800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=31, stack(0x00007f3ec9eff000,0x00007f3eca000000)]
    =>0x00007f3ef00ee800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=30, stack(0x00007f3ed00c0000,0x00007f3ed01c1000)]
      0x00007f3ef00ec800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29, stack(0x00007f3ed01c1000,0x00007f3ed02c2000)]
      0x00007f3ef00ea800 JavaThread "Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28, stack(0x00007f3ed02c2000,0x00007f3ed03c3000)]
      0x00007f3ef00bd000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=27, stack(0x00007f3ee00e9000,0x00007f3ee01ea000)]
      0x00007f3ef00bb000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=26, stack(0x00007f3ee01ea000,0x00007f3ee02eb000)]
      0x00007f3ef000a800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=19, stack(0x00007f3ef958d000,0x00007f3ef968e000)]

    Other Threads:
      0x00007f3ef00b6000 VMThread [stack: 0x00007f3ee02eb000,0x00007f3ee03ec000] [id=25]
      0x00007f3ef0103000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00007f3ec9bfc000,0x00007f3ec9cfd000] [id=34]

    VM state:synchronizing (normal execution)

    VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
    [0x00007f3ef0006d50] Safepoint_lock - owner thread: 0x00007f3ef00b6000
    [0x00007f3ef0006dd0] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x00007f3ef00b6000
    [0x00007f3ef0007350] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x00007f3e843a0000

    Heap:
     par new generation   total 39296K, used 38500K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c2aa0000, 0x00000006d4cc0000)
      eden space 34944K, 100% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c2220000, 0x00000006c2220000)
      from space 4352K,  81% used [0x00000006c2220000, 0x00000006c2599230, 0x00000006c2660000)
      to   space 4352K,   0% used [0x00000006c2660000, 0x00000006c2660000, 0x00000006c2aa0000)
     concurrent mark-sweep generation total 2411532K, used 1171734K [0x00000006d4cc0000, 0x0000000767fc3000, 0x00000007c0000000)
     Metaspace       used 163878K, capacity 167946K, committed 168816K, reserved 1200128K
      class space    used 17529K, capacity 18218K, committed 18404K, reserved 1048576K

    Card table byte_map: [0x00007f3ef508d000,0x00007f3ef588e000] byte_map_base: 0x00007f3ef1a8d000

    Marking Bits: (CMSBitMap*) 0x00007f3ef0062778
     Bits: [0x00007f3ed0532000, 0x00007f3ed3fff000)

    Mod Union Table: (CMSBitMap*) 0x00007f3ef0062838
     Bits: [0x00007f3ef4443000, 0x00007f3ef452e340)

    Polling page: 0x00007f3ef9698000

    CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=139460Kb max_used=139584Kb free=106299Kb
     bounds [0x00007f3ee1000000, 0x00007f3ee9990000, 0x00007f3ef0000000]
     total_blobs=33749 nmethods=32753 adapters=905
     compilation: enabled

    Compilation events (10 events):
    Event: 120723.158 Thread 0x00007f3ef00ee800 nmethod 48717 0x00007f3ee6668bd0 code [0x00007f3ee6668d20, 0x00007f3ee6668e78]
    Event: 120723.159 Thread 0x00007f3ef00ee800 48718       4       za.co.bsg.ems.server.model.entity.employee.ContactDetail::$javassist_write_email (42 bytes)
    Event: 120723.161 Thread 0x00007f3ef00f0800 48719       4       za.co.bsg.ems.server.model.entity.employee.ContactDetail::setCellNumber (6 bytes)
    Event: 120723.161 Thread 0x00007f3ef00ee800 nmethod 48718 0x00007f3ee3c26210 code [0x00007f3ee3c26360, 0x00007f3ee3c264b8]
    Event: 120723.163 Thread 0x00007f3ef00f0800 nmethod 48719 0x00007f3ee4a2b9d0 code [0x00007f3ee4a2bb20, 0x00007f3ee4a2bc78]
    Event: 120725.615 Thread 0x00007f3ef00f0800 48720   !   4       za.co.bsg.ems.server.webservices.MWLWebServiceImpl$EmployeeImporter::run (7696 bytes)
    Event: 120730.069 Thread 0x00007f3ef00f0800 nmethod 48720 0x00007f3ee9932f10 code [0x00007f3ee9936d80, 0x00007f3ee9952f80]
    Event: 120738.799 Thread 0x00007f3ef00f0800 48721       4       za.co.bsg.ems.server.util.Util::getAbsYearsBetween (26 bytes)
    Event: 120738.805 Thread 0x00007f3ef00f0800 nmethod 48721 0x00007f3ee34f0fd0 code [0x00007f3ee34f1220, 0x00007f3ee34f16c8]
    Event: 120738.842 Thread 0x00007f3ef00ee800 48722 % !   4       za.co.bsg.ems.server.webservices.MWLWebServiceImpl$EmployeeImporter::run @ 5562 (7696 bytes)

    GC Heap History (10 events):
    Event: 120737.500 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=76831 (full 271):
     par new generation   total 39296K, used 35331K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c2aa0000, 0x00000006d4cc0000)
      eden space 34944K, 100% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c2220000, 0x00000006c2220000)
      from space 4352K,   8% used [0x00000006c2660000, 0x00000006c26c0dc0, 0x00000006c2aa0000)
      to   space 4352K,   0% used [0x00000006c2220000, 0x00000006c2220000, 0x00000006c2660000)
     concurrent mark-sweep generation total 2411532K, used 1171122K [0x00000006d4cc0000, 0x0000000767fc3000, 0x00000007c0000000)
     Metaspace       used 163878K, capacity 167946K, committed 168816K, reserved 1200128K
      class space    used 17529K, capacity 18218K, committed 18404K, reserved 1048576K
    Event: 120737.516 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=76832 (full 271):
     par new generation   total 39296K, used 111K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c2aa0000, 0x00000006d4cc0000)
      eden space 34944K,   0% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c2220000)
      from space 4352K,   2% used [0x00000006c2220000, 0x00000006c223bee0, 0x00000006c2660000)
      to   space 4352K,   0% used [0x00000006c2660000, 0x00000006c2660000, 0x00000006c2aa0000)
     concurrent mark-sweep generation total 2411532K, used 1171134K [0x00000006d4cc0000, 0x0000000767fc3000, 0x00000007c0000000)
     Metaspace       used 163878K, capacity 167946K, committed 168816K, reserved 1200128K
      class space    used 17529K, capacity 18218K, committed 18404K, reserved 1048576K
    }
    Event: 120737.866 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=76832 (full 271):
     par new generation   total 39296K, used 35055K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c2aa0000, 0x00000006d4cc0000)
      eden space 34944K, 100% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c2220000, 0x00000006c2220000)
      from space 4352K,   2% used [0x00000006c2220000, 0x00000006c223bee0, 0x00000006c2660000)
      to   space 4352K,   0% used [0x00000006c2660000, 0x00000006c2660000, 0x00000006c2aa0000)
     concurrent mark-sweep generation total 2411532K, used 1171134K [0x00000006d4cc0000, 0x0000000767fc3000, 0x00000007c0000000)
     Metaspace       used 163878K, capacity 167946K, committed 168816K, reserved 1200128K
      class space    used 17529K, capacity 18218K, committed 18404K, reserved 1048576K
    Event: 120737.873 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=76833 (full 271):
     par new generation   total 39296K, used 749K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c2aa0000, 0x00000006d4cc0000)
      eden space 34944K,   0% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c2220000)
      from space 4352K,  17% used [0x00000006c2660000, 0x00000006c271b6c8, 0x00000006c2aa0000)
      to   space 4352K,   0% used [0x00000006c2220000, 0x00000006c2220000, 0x00000006c2660000)
     concurrent mark-sweep generation total 2411532K, used 1171143K [0x00000006d4cc0000, 0x0000000767fc3000, 0x00000007c0000000)
     Metaspace       used 163878K, capacity 167946K, committed 168816K, reserved 1200128K
      class space    used 17529K, capacity 18218K, committed 18404K, reserved 1048576K
    }
    Event: 120738.158 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=76833 (full 271):
     par new generation   total 39296K, used 35693K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c2aa0000, 0x00000006d4cc0000)
      eden space 34944K, 100% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c2220000, 0x00000006c2220000)
      from space 4352K,  17% used [0x00000006c2660000, 0x00000006c271b6c8, 0x00000006c2aa0000)
      to   space 4352K,   0% used [0x00000006c2220000, 0x00000006c2220000, 0x00000006c2660000)
     concurrent mark-sweep generation total 2411532K, used 1171143K [0x00000006d4cc0000, 0x0000000767fc3000, 0x00000007c0000000)
     Metaspace       used 163878K, capacity 167946K, committed 168816K, reserved 1200128K
      class space    used 17529K, capacity 18218K, committed 18404K, reserved 1048576K
    Event: 120738.165 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=76834 (full 271):
     par new generation   total 39296K, used 1770K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c2aa0000, 0x00000006d4cc0000)
      eden space 34944K,   0% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c2220000)
      from space 4352K,  40% used [0x00000006c2220000, 0x00000006c23dab20, 0x00000006c2660000)
      to   space 4352K,   0% used [0x00000006c2660000, 0x00000006c2660000, 0x00000006c2aa0000)
     concurrent mark-sweep generation total 2411532K, used 1171152K [0x00000006d4cc0000, 0x0000000767fc3000, 0x00000007c0000000)
     Metaspace       used 163878K, capacity 167946K, committed 168816K, reserved 1200128K
      class space    used 17529K, capacity 18218K, committed 18404K, reserved 1048576K
    }
    Event: 120738.459 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=76834 (full 271):
     par new generation   total 39296K, used 36714K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c2aa0000, 0x00000006d4cc0000)
      eden space 34944K, 100% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c2220000, 0x00000006c2220000)
      from space 4352K,  40% used [0x00000006c2220000, 0x00000006c23dab20, 0x00000006c2660000)
      to   space 4352K,   0% used [0x00000006c2660000, 0x00000006c2660000, 0x00000006c2aa0000)
     concurrent mark-sweep generation total 2411532K, used 1171152K [0x00000006d4cc0000, 0x0000000767fc3000, 0x00000007c0000000)
     Metaspace       used 163878K, capacity 167946K, committed 168816K, reserved 1200128K
      class space    used 17529K, capacity 18218K, committed 18404K, reserved 1048576K
    Event: 120738.467 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=76835 (full 271):
     par new generation   total 39296K, used 3391K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c2aa0000, 0x00000006d4cc0000)
      eden space 34944K,   0% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c2220000)
      from space 4352K,  77% used [0x00000006c2660000, 0x00000006c29afd80, 0x00000006c2aa0000)
      to   space 4352K,   0% used [0x00000006c2220000, 0x00000006c2220000, 0x00000006c2660000)
     concurrent mark-sweep generation total 2411532K, used 1171161K [0x00000006d4cc0000, 0x0000000767fc3000, 0x00000007c0000000)
     Metaspace       used 163878K, capacity 167946K, committed 168816K, reserved 1200128K
      class space    used 17529K, capacity 18218K, committed 18404K, reserved 1048576K
    }
    Event: 120738.759 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=76835 (full 271):
     par new generation   total 39296K, used 38335K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c2aa0000, 0x00000006d4cc0000)
      eden space 34944K, 100% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c2220000, 0x00000006c2220000)
      from space 4352K,  77% used [0x00000006c2660000, 0x00000006c29afd80, 0x00000006c2aa0000)
      to   space 4352K,   0% used [0x00000006c2220000, 0x00000006c2220000, 0x00000006c2660000)
     concurrent mark-sweep generation total 2411532K, used 1171161K [0x00000006d4cc0000, 0x0000000767fc3000, 0x00000007c0000000)
     Metaspace       used 163878K, capacity 167946K, committed 168816K, reserved 1200128K
      class space    used 17529K, capacity 18218K, committed 18404K, reserved 1048576K
    Event: 120738.768 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=76836 (full 271):
     par new generation   total 39296K, used 3556K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c2aa0000, 0x00000006d4cc0000)
      eden space 34944K,   0% used [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c2220000)
      from space 4352K,  81% used [0x00000006c2220000, 0x00000006c2599230, 0x00000006c2660000)
      to   space 4352K,   0% used [0x00000006c2660000, 0x00000006c2660000, 0x00000006c2aa0000)
     concurrent mark-sweep generation total 2411532K, used 1171734K [0x00000006d4cc0000, 0x0000000767fc3000, 0x00000007c0000000)
     Metaspace       used 163878K, capacity 167946K, committed 168816K, reserved 1200128K
      class space    used 17529K, capacity 18218K, committed 18404K, reserved 1048576K
    }

    Deoptimization events (10 events):
    Event: 118666.938 Thread 0x00007f3ecc052800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f3ee6f3f12c method=com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(Lcom/sun/xml/internal/bind/v2/runtime/unmarshaller/TagName;)V @ 41
    Event: 118667.043 Thread 0x00007f3ecc052800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f3ee5a16de4 method=com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.read([CII)I @ 897
    Event: 118667.062 Thread 0x00007f3ecc052800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f3ee72dd9b8 method=com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.parseAttrValue(CLcom/ctc/wstx/util/TextBuilder;)V @ 194
    Event: 118667.308 Thread 0x00007f3ecc052800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f3ee665a510 method=com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.loadMore(I)Z @ 111
    Event: 118679.690 Thread 0x00007f3e8456e000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f3ee66cc98c method=com.tc.net.core.TCConnectionImpl$WriteContext.getPackedUpMessage([Lcom/tc/bytes/TCByteBuffer;)[Lcom/tc/bytes/TCByteBuffer; @ 199
    Event: 118692.096 Thread 0x00007f3ef00bd000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f3ee1be787c method=java.io.FileInputStream.finalize()V @ 18
    Event: 120298.322 Thread 0x00007f3ecc0a9000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f3ee6f3f12c method=com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(Lcom/sun/xml/internal/bind/v2/runtime/unmarshaller/TagName;)V @ 41
    Event: 120298.470 Thread 0x00007f3ecc0a9000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f3ee6654ebc method=com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.read([CII)I @ 453
    Event: 120389.901 Thread 0x00007f3ef00bd000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f3ee1be787c method=java.io.FileInputStream.finalize()V @ 18
    Event: 120654.748 Thread 0x000000000258d800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f3ee78f9afc method=za.co.bsg.ems.server.services.employee.UpdateEmployeeDateService.updateEmploymentPeriodDates(Lza/co/bsg/ems/server/model/entity/EmploymentPeriod;Ljava/util/Date;Ljava/util/D

    Internal exceptions (10 events):
    Event: 115289.919 Thread 0x00007f3e87ab2000 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x00000006c101a258) thrown at [/tmp/buildd/openjdk-8-8u66-b17/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
    Event: 115289.961 Thread 0x00007f3e794d2800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x00000006c1023640) thrown at [/tmp/buildd/openjdk-8-8u66-b17/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
    Event: 115303.455 Thread 0x000000000240c000 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketException': Socket closed> (0x00000006c00209e0) thrown at [/tmp/buildd/openjdk-8-8u66-b17/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
    Event: 115359.074 Thread 0x00007f3ecc052800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x00000006c1fd1150) thrown at [/tmp/buildd/openjdk-8-8u66-b17/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]...
```

Comment: Are you using JNI anywhere? I have seen such errors many times due ti bad JNI programming

Comment: Report it at http://bugs.java.com/

Comment: It depends on which GWT version you are using, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693169/java-8-support-in-gwt

Comment: @Jens if you read my question you will see that I have already done that.

Comment: @DawidPura I highly doubt this has anything to do with GWT, this is a pure server-side issue and it occurred while a daily import was running - pure back-end stuff GWT was not involved at all.

Comment: @AnandVaidya no I am not (at least not directly / intentionally)

Comment: I do not think that anyone here can read the dump

Comment: @Jens to clarify, I'm not asking for anyone to interpret the dump for me, all I am asking is: has anyone come across this type of error before (Internal Error (loopnode.hpp:609), pid=17, tid=139907756197632
guarantee(n != NULL) failed: No Node.) and found a solution for it through whatever means